# Why does the Object class in Java contain protected methods?

Tags: java, oop, object, inheritance, protected

Why does the [Object class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html) in Java contain protected methods, such as [`clone()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#clone()) and [`finalize()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#finalize()), if all classes you use or write inherit the instance methods of Object?

Comment: So derived classes inherit it without it being public?

Comment: `protected` members are only visible to classes in the same package or subclasses. Clarify your question.

Comment: In OOP, protected is preferable over public method if designed for inheritance.

Comment: The question is rather why you find it so surprising. If you understand what 'protected' means, the answer is the same for Object as it is for any other class.

Comment: Thanks for comments, In Object class only two protected methods - clone() and finalize(). The point of the question - if any classes inherit Object, that's mean these methods visible for all classes. Than for what purpose Object class design this way? That was my question.

Comment: @EJP I can understand why it's surprising.  The usual simple explanation is that a public member is available to all other classes, and a protected member is available only to subclasses of that class.  But if everything is a subclass of Object, then that means there's no difference, right?  So why make some of them `protected`?  That's where I think the OP is coming from.  The truth, though, is that there are additional consequences of `protected` that go beyond the simple explanation, e.g. affecting what access modifier can go on an override.

Comment: @ajb I don't find guesswork about what OP might think even slightly interesting. It is up to him to clarify his question, explain his surprise, etc.

Comment: @EJP Except that your earlier comment sort of implied that he must be somewhat ignorant in order to be so surprised.  If you don't think I should speculate on his thinking, then you probably shouldn't speculate on his ignorance or lack thereof either.  In truth, the same question had occurred to me several months earlier, for the reasons I spelled out, and it took a bit of thinking to figure out why they would have bothered; it's nontrivial.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If class `C2` extends `C1`, and `C1` contains a `public` method, then the method in `C2` (if overridden) must also be `public`; Java makes it illegal to put additional restrictions on a method's access when overriding.  If `C1` contains a `protected` method, then an overriding method in `C2` may be `protected` or `public`.

These rules apply even if `C1` is the `Object` class.
So I think the reason is so that classes (which all inherit from `Object`) can declare their own overriding `clone` and `finalize` methods and make them `protected` if they choose, instead of `public`.

**EDIT:** An important consequence of this is that `clone` and `finalize` are not as freely  accessible as a public member would be.  Within class `C2`, you can use `clone` and `finalize` on an object of type `C2` all you want, since they are protected methods and therefore available to the subclass `C2`.  But you can't necessarily use them on objects of another class.

```
class X { }

class Y {
    private Y field1;
    private X field2;
    public void foo() throws Exception {
        Object o1 = this.clone();      // legal
        Object o2 = field1.clone();    // legal
        Object o3 = field2.clone();    // illegal
        String s1 = field2.toString(); // legal since toString() is "public" in Object
    }
}
```

This should demonstrate that although `protected` methods are accessible to subclasses, there are still some restrictions on how accessible they are.  Note that if `X` had an `@Override public Object clone()` method, then the declaration of `o3` would become legal.

Answer (score 5):

There are two `protected` methods in `Object`: `clone()` and `finalize()`.

`finalize()` is **not** intended to be called by client code, but may be overridden by subclasses - thus, it is protected.

`clone()` of `Object` is not intended to be called by clients either - unless it has explicitly been overridden and made `public` by a subclass.

Answer (score 4):

This is done because for generic abstract `Object` it is unclear what to do if user wants to `clone` it for example, or `finalize`. That's why we have a chance to override this methods and create our own implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Object class contains finalise() and clone() method with protected modifier so that developer can decide whether these method can be overridden with protected or public modifier.Means it totally depends on the requirement wether we are going to allow  client code to call these methods or not.