# Why The methods in Object Class Are Protected?

Tags: java

Why the Methods In class Object Are Protected And why its not public is there any valid reason?

```
protected native Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException;
```

Comment: It's an _implementation detail_ of how Java handles cloning. IMO doc about [Cloneable interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Cloneable.html) can help (_per-se_ you may even have a public Object.clone() method, even if throwing an exception almost always, but with this _pattern_ you separate basic _behavior_ given by base class).

Answer (score 1):

If class C2 extends C1, and C1 contains a public method, then the method in C2 (if overridden) must also be public; Java makes it illegal to put additional restrictions on a method's access when overriding. If C1 contains a protected method, then an overriding method in C2 may be protected or public.

Here is the **stackoverflow** accepted answer for more details

[Why does the Object class in Java contain protected methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23096305/why-object-class-in-java-contains-protected-method)

Answer (score 0):

This allows the designer of a class to decide whether or not is is appropriate for the class to support cloning.  The `protected` `Object.clone()` method is what a class *calls* to implement cloning ... if it wants to the native cloning mechanism.

If I want my class to be cloneable, I add a public clone method; e.g.

```
public class MyClass implements Cloneable {
    ....
    public Object clone() {
        super.clone();
    }
}
```

If I want cloning to be available *internally*, I write:

```
public class MyClass implements Cloneable {
    ....
    // Don't provide a public override for `clone()`.
}
```

If I want no cloning, I write:

```
public class MyClass {
    ...
}
```

---

By contrast, if `Object.clone()` was `public`, then every object would notionally support cloning ... as far as the compiler is concerned!  That would be a bad thing, because there are a lot of classes where cloning makes no sense, is harmful, or cannot be implemented.

---

In the case of `finalize()`, it would be harmful if arbitrary code could initiate the finalization logic on an object.  It only makes sense for the GC to do this, or in some cases for the class and its subclasses to do this.

Note that if you do implement a `finalize()` method it is advisable to chain to the superclass `finalize()`; e.g.

```
  protected void finalize() {
      // Do my finalization
      super.finalize();
  }
```

... even if the superclass *currently* have a finalizer.

Comment: `By contrast, if Object.clone() was public, then every object would notionally support cloning ... ` this is applicable even if the Object.clone is protected since all subclasses are allowed access to protected methods, and all classes are subclasses of Object class

Comment: That's not true.  The access means that a method of some class can call `clone()` on `this` or on some other instance of the same class or a subclass.   It does not allow `clone()` to be called on an instance of an unrelated class.   Try it!